# Active Record Query ignoring nil values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Takes a query using some methods like code bellow. How can I ignore the `nil` values? For example: if the method `date` returns `nil` I wanna that the query use just `array_one` and `array_to`.

```
def array_one 
 ...
end 

def array_two 
 ...
end

def date 
 ...
end

Record.where(array_one: array_one, array_two: array_two, date: date)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can chain your queries together (it's called lazy loading). They won't actually be executed until the first thing that calls query. This allows you to 'build' the query

```
query = Record.where(array_one: array_one, array_two: array_two)
query = query.where(date: date) if date.present?

query.each do |row| # now the query is executed
  # do stuff
end
```

Comment: Why is `.where(array_one: array_one, array_two: array_two)` split into two rows?

Comment: Because are different rows on DB.

Comment: No, its not because of that. It's because you want to dynamically build a query based on conditions. Based on your original question you want to exclude `.where(date: ...)` if date is nil, which is exactly what the code above does. It doesn't matter how you split it up. Also, mark answers as chosen once you get it. Cheers

Comment: @Виктор i split it up arbitrarily to show the query still works. He can group them or not group them, however he sees fit

Comment: Makse sense, was just wondering if there's more going on there, +1

Answer (score 4):

```
Record.where({ array_one: array_one, array_two: array_two, date: date }.compact)
```

Comment: All this time I've been programming Ruby, and I didn't know about Hash#compact.  Nice.

Comment: I didn't know about this too, awesome!

Comment: Maybe because it is still kind of new, it was added with version Ruby 2.4.0?

Comment: sorry, but in Rails Hash#compact supported since 4.1.8 https://apidock.com/rails/v4.1.8/Hash/compact

Answer (score 3):

I would do something like this:

```
scope = Record.scope
scope = scope.where(array_one: array_one) if array_one
scope = scope.where(array_two: array_two) if array_two
scope = scope.where(date: date) if date
scope
```

Comment: What does the first line do ?

Comment: It starts with whatever scope is already in existence when you call the method.

Comment: @Виктор It creates a new scope.  Every ActiveRecord query starts with a new scope, usually automatically where you can't see it.  For example, `Record.where...` is equivalent to `Record.scope.where`.

Comment: And it make sure that you get a Relation returned even if all conditions are false